# How to write a CASE in a group by with Linq-To-Sql?

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

In ASP.NET 4, I'm trying to write a case statement in a group by with LINQ-To-SQL.
For example, I'm trying to do this:

```
Select ...
FROM Table T
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN T.COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN T.COLUMN2 
            ELSE T.COLUMN3 
         END
```

How would you translate that query in LINQ?

Comment: See what you can come up with using nested ternary operators and come back with your work. We can't give you a sample implementation because you didn't specify your language (C#/VB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
from t in T
group t by (t.Column1 == null ? t.Column2 : t.Column3) into grp
select ... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
   var result = 
   from item in T
   group item by new { YourColumn = ((item.Column1 == null) ?  item.Column2  : item.Column3) } into g
   select g;
```